# python: how to put element in the right column of csv file?

Tags: python

Good Morning
i just opened another post but was closed because someone wrote is duplicated... i don't know

I have a csv file with 3 headers and now i need to add the elements estracted in each column, my code add the elements only in the first column, how i can change it?

```
import csv

from = "12/03/2022"
to = "19/03/2022"
price = "350"

with open('voli.csv','r+') as file:
file.write("FROM TO COST")
file.write("\n")
file.write(from)
file.write(to)
file.write(price)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding any separator between your values that's why they are being written together. Try the following code :

```
import csv

from_date = "12/03/2022"
to_date = "19/03/2022"
price = "350"

with open('voli.csv','r+') as file:
  file.write("FROM TO COST")
  file.write("\n")
  file.write(f"{from_date} {to_date} {price}\n")
```

Note: from is a python keyword so you need to change that variable name.

I also see that you imported the csv library. If you want to use that you can do it like this :

```
import csv

from_date = "12/03/2022"
to_date = "19/03/2022"
price = "350"

with open('voli.csv','r+') as file:
  csvwriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=" ")
  csvwriter.writerow(["FROM", "TO", "COST"])
  csvwriter.writerow([from_date, to_date, price])
```

Comment: yes, correct, i used "from" only for english translation, but i wrote the variable in italian language. I check your code and finally it work very good. Thank you!!!